# Category partition in Shiny: R

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, categories

I would like to improve a Shiny application that already appeared in this forum. I would like to achieve such an effect that, for example, by choosing Category1 "**a**", the category "**a, b**" was also shown. Similarly, when selecting the "c" Category1, all other categories containing "**c**" should be visible, in this case "**c, b**".

## Code:

```
library(shiny)

data.input <- data.frame(
  Category1 = rep(sample(c("a,b","a","c,b","b", "c"), 45, replace = T)),
  Info = paste("Text info", 1:45),
  Category2 = sample(letters[15:20], 45, replace = T),
  Size = sample(1:100, 45),
  MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff", 1:45)
)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                      "show_vars",
                      "Columns to show:",
                      choices = colnames(data.input),  # edit
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = c("Category1", "Info", "Category2")
                    ),
                    actionButton("button", "An action button"),
                    uiOutput("category1"),
                    uiOutput("category2"),
                    uiOutput("sizeslider")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data.react <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    data.input[, input$show_vars]
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$category1 <- renderUI({
      data.sel <- data.react()
      selectizeInput('cat1',
                     'Choose Cat 1',
                     choices = c("All", sort(as.character(
                       unique(data.sel$Category1)
                     ))),
                     selected = "All")
    })

    df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1, {
      data.sel <- data.react()
      if (input$cat1 == "All") {
        data.sel
      }
      else{
        data.sel[data.sel$Category1 == input$cat1,]
      }
    })

    output$category2 <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(
        'cat2',
        'Choose Cat 2 (optional):',
        choices = sort(as.character(unique(
          df_subset()$Category2
        ))),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = NULL
      )
    })

    df_subset1 <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$cat2)) {
        df_subset()
      } else {
        df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,]
      }
    })

    output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(
        "size",
        label = "Size Range",
        min = min(data.input$Size),
        max = max(data.input$Size),
        value = c(min(data.input$Size), max(data.input$Size))
      )
    })

    df_subset2 <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$size)) {
        df_subset1()
      } else {
        df_subset1()[data.input$Size >= input$size[1] &
                       data.input$Size <= input$size[2],]
      }
    })
    output$table <- renderTable({
      df_subset2()

    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Expected effect:

[image]

## Changed version:

[image]

I would like the **abc** not to show up in **bc**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is using `grepl` and `sapply`. You could use:

`slt <- sapply(X = data.sel$Category1, FUN = grepl, pattern = input$cat1 )`
So you would get all the rows in catergory 1 that has the string.

In your code it would be something like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data.react <- eventReactive(input$button, {
      data.input[, input$show_vars]
    })
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      output$category1 <- renderUI({
        data.sel <- data.react()
        selectizeInput('cat1',
                       'Choose Cat 1',
                       choices = c("All", sort(as.character(
                         unique(data.sel$Category1)
                       ))),
                       selected = "All")
      })

      df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1, {
        data.sel <- data.react()
        if (input$cat1 == "All") {


            data.sel
            }
            else{
###########################This part has been added#######################
                  slt <- sapply(X = data.sel$Category1, FUN = grepl, pattern = input$cat1 )
                  data.sel[slt,]
##################################################################
    # data.sel[data.sel$Category1 == input$cat1,]
            }
          })

      output$category2 <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput(
          'cat2',
          'Choose Cat 2 (optional):',
          choices = sort(as.character(unique(
            df_subset()$Category2
          ))),
          multiple = TRUE,
          options = NULL
        )
      })

      df_subset1 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$cat2)) {
          df_subset()
        } else {
          df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,]
        }
      })

      output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
        sliderInput(
          "size",
          label = "Size Range",
          min = min(data.input$Size),
          max = max(data.input$Size),
          value = c(min(data.input$Size), max(data.input$Size))
        )
      })

      df_subset2 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$size)) {
          df_subset1()
        } else {
          df_subset1()[data.input$Size >= input$size[1] &
                         data.input$Size <= input$size[2],]
        }
      })
      output$table <- renderTable({
        df_subset2()

      })
    })
  }
```

With this modification your output would look like this[image]

Hope it helps!

**EDIT1:**

Since comma separated words was you actually wanted I guess this approach would maybe help you.

```
slt <- sapply(X= data.sel$Category1, FUN = function(x, y){
                ele1 <-  unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split = ",")))
                ele2 <-  unique(unlist(strsplit(y, split = ",")))
                if(any(ele1 == ele2))
                  return(TRUE)
                else
                  return(FALSE)

              },y=input$cat1

              )
```

**EDIT2:**
Here is the full code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data.react <- eventReactive(input$button, {
      data.input[, input$show_vars]
    })
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      output$category1 <- renderUI({
        data.sel <- data.react()
        selectizeInput('cat1',
                       'Choose Cat 1',
                       choices = c("All", sort(as.character(
                         unique(data.sel$Category1)
                       ))),
                       selected = "All")
      })

      df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1, {
        data.sel <- data.react()
        if (input$cat1 == "All") {


          data.sel
        }
        else{
          ###########################This part has been added#######################
          # slt <- sapply(X = data.sel$Category1, FUN = grepl, pattern = input$cat1 )
          slt <- sapply(X= data.sel$Category1, FUN = function(x, y){
            ele1 <-  unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split = ",")))
            ele2 <-  unique(unlist(strsplit(y, split = ",")))
            if(any(ele1 == ele2))
              return(TRUE)
            else
              return(FALSE)

          },y=input$cat1

          )
          data.sel[slt,]
          ##################################################################
          # data.sel[data.sel$Category1 == input$cat1,]
        }
      })

      output$category2 <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput(
          'cat2',
          'Choose Cat 2 (optional):',
          choices = sort(as.character(unique(
            df_subset()$Category2
          ))),
          multiple = TRUE,
          options = NULL
        )
      })

      df_subset1 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$cat2)) {
          df_subset()
        } else {
          df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,]
        }
      })

      output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
        sliderInput(
          "size",
          label = "Size Range",
          min = min(data.input$Size),
          max = max(data.input$Size),
          value = c(min(data.input$Size), max(data.input$Size))
        )
      })

      df_subset2 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$size)) {
          df_subset1()
        } else {
          df_subset1()[data.input$Size >= input$size[1] &
                         data.input$Size <= input$size[2],]
        }
      })
      output$table <- renderTable({
        df_subset2()

      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: It's almost okay, however, when in Category 1 I will add the names "abc" and "bc" the program does not work well. Because "bc" can not be in "abc". I changed the screen above and see what I mean.

Comment: I thought to use `unique(unlist(strsplit(data.sel$Category1, split = ","))))`.

Comment: Do you mean to say that  if I select c bc is allowed but abc is not allowed?

Comment: Okay I get it, the `,` means that they are seperate letters while when we do not have a comma it is one word...

Comment: No, commas are important here, eg `"a"` can be in `"a, b"`, but in can not be in `"abc"`.

Comment: Yes exactly. :)

Comment: I have edited the code have a look, maybe this will work.

Comment: Did you put the code in the same place? Because the mistake throws me right away. `Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

Comment: It works beautifully, I forgot about one line `data.sel[slt,]`. Thank you very much.